# Django question on assigning the created news/team to the user who created it

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

please help me with one question, if possible.

I have a profile model that has a OneToOneField to User and there is a team field in the Profile model, there is also a Team model with a name, tag, etc. I would like to ask how to make the user who creates the team immediately be in it, so that the team field of the Profile model is assigned this team automatically, so that he is its creator and captain immediately. Maybe someone can help, explain, throw a banal example for understanding.

The creation was done like this, in a separate application. But I don't understand how to give the browser the created tim.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from slugify import slugify
from django.urls import reverse


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Profile(BaseModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
    )
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, null=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey('Team', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self._state.adding is True:
            Profile.objects.create()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nickname

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Автор"
        verbose_name_plural = "Авторы"


class Team(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=50)
    tag = models.CharField('Тег', max_length=16, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} [{self.tag}]'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("team_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Team, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Команда"
        verbose_name_plural = "Команды"
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import TextInput, Textarea, FileInput, IntegerField
from django.forms import TextInput, Textarea, FileInput, Select

from .models import *


class CreateTeamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = {
            'name', 'tag', 'slug'
        }
```

**views.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, get_user_model
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, resolve_url
from django.utils.http import url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme
from django.views.generic.base import View
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from .models import *
from .forms import *


# Create your views here.


class CreateTeam(View):

    def get(self, request):
        form = CreateTeamForm(request.POST)
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'team/home.html', context)

    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateTeamForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('home')
            return redirect('home')
```

I'm just learning django, so it's hard to implement everything at once, and I'll be happy to help.

**NEW CODE**

**forms.py**

```
class JoinTeamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    key = forms.CharField(label='key', max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = {'key'}
```

I tried without key = forms.CharField(label='key', max_length=20), but in html {{ form.key }} didn't work.

**views.py**

```
class JoinTeam(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, pk):
        print(f'post:{request.POST}, get:{request.GET}')
        form = JoinTeamForm(request.POST or None)
        team = Team.objects.get(id=pk)
        context = {'form': form,
                   'team': team
                   }
        return render(request, 'team/team_detail.html', context)

    def post(self, request, pk):
        print(f'post: {request.POST} team_id: {Team.objects.get(id=pk).key}')
        profile = request.user.profile
        error_msg = 'Неверный код'
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = JoinTeamForm(request.POST)
            role = Role.objects.get(id=2)
            team = Team.objects.get(id=pk)
            if form.is_valid():
                key = form.save()
                if key == team.key:
                    profile.team = team
                    profile.role = role
                    profile.save()
                    return redirect(team.get_absolute_url())
                else:
                    return HttpResponse(error_msg)
            return redirect(team.get_absolute_url())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you edit your view to update the user's profile after the team is created?

```
class CreateTeam(View):

    def get(self, request):
        form = CreateTeamForm(request.POST)
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'team/home.html', context)

    def post(self, request):
        profile = request.user.profile
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateTeamForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                team = form.save()
                profile.team = team
                profile.save()
                return redirect('home')
            return redirect('home')
```

Please note, the way you have this set up is that each profile can only be on one team. If that's your intent, great, but if not you may want to set up a many to many model here so a user can be associated with multiple teams.

Comment: Ooohh, thank you, man. I didn't really think about it, it was so simple. I thought about a similar model, but I didn't know how to implement it correctly. Yes, I did make a special fk instead of m2m.

Comment: with one message you solved 2-3 of my problems xd

Comment: Sorry for another stupid question, maybe you can also help, I'm trying to make joining the team only by code. The code is generated automatically. But when I try to write code in the view, it doesn't work normally and it feels like I'm doing it wrong in the Form and it tries not to check the key, but to create a command because of my model. Added a view and form with an html page to the main question.